# Event handles in multiple hierarchies React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a third party component that wraps a button:

```
<ExtComponent> <!-- this component has it's own internal onClick handler -->
  <button />
</ExtComponent>
```

That component has an internal `onClick` event handler that takes precedence over any onClick I am trying to add to `<button>`. So when I do

```
<ExtComponent> <!-- this component has it's own internal onClick handler -->
  <button onClick={this.onClick} /> <!-- this is not being triggered as ExtComponent onClick is being called instead -->
</ExtComponent>
```

my component onClick is not being called.

Is there any way to first handle the sub-component (button) onClick and then continue (or not) to the ExtComponent onClick ?

*(Assuming I can change the 3rd party component (I can fork and change it))*

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469968/can-we-attach-click-handlers-to-custom-child-components

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Does clicking the button call the wrong handler, or does it not trigger at all? Can you provide an example of what the HTML looks like after the component is rendered?

Comment: @DanPrince this is more of a general question, I updated the question to be more clear

Comment: I know but even in a general case, React components can't have event handlers that respond to clicks, as they aren't rendered into the DOM.

Which element is the internal click handler attached to and what is the hierarchical relationship between it and the button?

Comment: @DanPrince The `ExtComponent` is eventually rendered into a `<div>` with an `onClick` handler that opens a dialog of some sort. I would like to conditionally open that dialog, depending on some prop, but since I have no access to that element I was asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to remove or update the click handler from the component. Just stop the event from ever getting there.

If the button is rendered inside the div that has the click handler, then you can [prevent the click event from propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) up to the div.

```
onClick: function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // now handle the click
}
```

If you want to allow the event to propagate on some condition, then simply don't stop the propagation.

```
onClick: function(event) {
  if(this.prop.foo == 'bar') {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    // let the event trigger the upper event listeners too
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like I had a problem that prevented my inner component to register a click event. Fixed that and I saw that indeed, like you say, the even bubbles from inside out and I can use `stopPropagation` to stop it. Sorry for that and thanks for pointing me to the right direction :-)